# Self referential functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recurrence-relations, recursion

I am currently attempting to work with a particularly annoying self-referential function; that is the function is defined in terms of itself and also takes $x$ as an input. This function is defined as follows:
$$b_{k+1}(x) = 3 \cdot b_k(x) + f(b_k(x)),\ b_1(x)=3x+1$$
The definition of $f(x)$ is not important here, but note that $f(x)$ cannot be simplified in any way that matters.
I want to show that 
$$b_k(x)=3^k x + 3^{k-1} + \sum_{n=2}^k 3^{k-n} \cdot f(b_{n-1}(x))$$
However, I do not know how I would come to this conclusion, or even if I have to prove it. I simply found it by observation. Looking around, I have found very little information about self-referential functions, only a lot about Tupper's self-referential formula.
How would I/should I prove this?

Comment: (1) I would presume in the recursive definition that you provided the term "$3\cdot b_k$" is supposed to be "$3\cdot b_k(x)$", isn't it? (2) Something's not right with your proposed formula. From the given recursive definition, by setting $k=0$, we'll get $b_1(x)=3+f(b_0(x))$. But from the proposed formula, by setting $k=1$, we'll get $b_1(x)=3x+f(b_1(x))$ instead. (3) I believe that your proposed formula can be corrected (I didn't work it out myself yet, which is why I'm only posting a comment, not an answer). And then it probably can be proven by induction.

Comment: You'll find more searching for recursion, recursion relations and recursive functions than self-referential functions. In particular you might want to start with linear homogeneous recursion relations since they're solvable and instructive.

Comment: zipirovich sorry youre right, I did make a mistake in the initial formula. it has been edited now to be $b_{k+1}(x)=3\cdot b_k(x)+f(b_k(x)), b_0(x)=1$

Comment: zipirovich you're right again, (although I didn't read your comment properly the first time), I made a fundamental error way back in my derivations. I somehow got $b_0(x) = 1$ from $b_1(x) = 3x+1$ (the original basic formula). this has been updated and corrected now, thank you.